# After the third wake up there is no sound on Line Out (Headphones) and Mic does not work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones, wakeup

After the third wake up, the sound on Line Out(Headphones) and Mic do not work on my Desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (fresh install, no upgrade), which are connected on the rear site. They also disappear from Settings --> Sound --> Output shows only HDMI/ DisplayPort 2 (which works) and Input (for Mic) is empty.

I get the following errors on the screen after wake up and also when I run **dmesg**:

```
[ 5799.219854] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219855] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219856] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219856] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219857] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219857] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219858] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219858] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219859] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
[ 5799.219859] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07
```

**lscpi -v:**

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at a4080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

**alsamixer** shows that Headphone and Rear Mic are muted:

[image: alsamixer]

**Specs:**

[image: neofetch]

I also tried adding different options on `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` at the end `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`, `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`, `options snd-hda-intel model=generic`, `options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1` but the issue is still available.

Running this fixes the issue:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

However I dont want this to run everytime there is no sound. Does someone know how to fix this ?

Comment: I just discovered this error in dmesg `snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x5f2f07` repeat 10 ten times after awaking the system from suspend mode. Issue: screens appeared after waking but went black/blank completedly, although programs are still running in the background. Kernel 5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu I had to reboot my system.